# Background image placing above navbar instead of background HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, background

I'm just beginning to learn Css and Html and am having an issue where my background image is stuck in the navbar. I have a logo but the background image is placing above the whole navbar and logo. There are several redundancies in these screenshots as I was fooling around with multiple ways of placing the image. I'm assuming this is a simple mistake any tips would be appreciated.

[contains style sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nq4q8.jpg)

[html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEC6D.jpg)

Comment: please add html and css code instead of adding screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

your position is relative on class hero (.hero) due to which it is showing above so change the position to absolute  hope it will help..

Answer (score 0):

You can try set nav-bar's z-index.

```
z-index:999;
```

If your nav-bar's z-index value is bigger than background-image's, your nav-bar will be over the background-image.